# Python Pandas: Best strategy to import heterogenious csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a inhomogenious csv-File I want to read into pandas. The file looks like that:

```
2016-01-01; 1.00; 2.00
2016-01-02; 1,10; 2.05
2016-01-03; 0.95; 1.90
Some other text in here
2016-01-04; 1.01; 2.04
Some more text there
2016-01-05; 1.06; 2.07
```

I only need the text lines so I can skip the lines starting with a date. I tried several strategies to read that in and filter our the required data but nothing worked so far. What I know is the Text-lines always start with a special word ("some" in this example). However, there is no fixed line number that can be used.

Comment: Have a look at the `comment` keyword for input routines. The documentation says: `Indicates remainder of line should not be parsed. If found at the beginning of a line, the line will be ignored altogether. ` See e.g. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to discard lines starting with a single special *character*, you can use the `comment` parameter of [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), as noted by @cel in the comment above.

Otherwise, you can use regular Python logic for filtering out items from an iterator, and use `CStringIO`.

For example, to discard the lines starting with `"some"`, you can use:

```
import CStringIO

buf = StringIO.StringIO('\n'.join((l for l in open('stuff.txt') if not l.startswith('Some'))))
pd.read_csv(buf, sep=';')
```

Conversely, if you actually only need lines starting with `"some"`, then use

```
buf = StringIO.StringIO('\n'.join((l for l in open('stuff.txt') if l.startswith('Some'))))
```

Comment: There is something missed up. In that case I exactly need the lines staerting with the word "Some", I don't need all the other lines.

Comment: @BastianLöffler See edit; does this answer your question?

Comment: I will look into this.  What is buf exactly? This is not yet a pandas dataframe I guess?

Comment: @BastianLöffler It's a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) - something that "looks like a file", but is sort of like a string. It's useful for what it sounds like - when you have an API that expects a file (like `read_csv`), but what you really have is a string.

Comment: Ok so all proposals go into what I was also thinking about: Doing some prework before reading into pandas. I just hoped there is an easy way to filter out in pandas.

Comment: @BastianLöffler Possibly (and this depends on your data), you can specify `comment='2'` in `read_csv`. If this doesn't fit in with your data, then, yeah, preprocessing is the way to go.